# Can I use my Nexus7 charger to charge my Android phone?

Tags: battery, charging

The Nexus charger has an OP Amp rating of 2A. The charger that comes with the phone has an OP Amp rating of 1A. Both have the same voltage. IP voltage is 100-250 V for both.

I googled and came across various posts saying how Li-ion batteries are smarter and how the phone will only draw as much power as it needs, and not more.

So essentially, the phone takes what it needs, and the charger is capable, but doesnt force its rated voltage on the device. Is this correct way of putting it?

Will it damage the battery in anyway? Or the charging circuit?

Comment: I've used my Nexus 7 charger on my Nexus S phone for the past 2 months or so and haven't noticed any ill effects yet.

Comment: I've plugged in any number of mini-USB power packs to my Galaxy Nexus (and before that, my DROID) and each worked just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: yes, you can use your Nexus7 charger to charge your Android phone. If the connectors are compatible, it will work without problems.

I always use a single 2A USB charger for every phone, tablet and ereader that I have at home, and also for the Raspberry PI.

Comment: It is convenient to carry a single charger. But a problem, when all devices are powerless at the same time.

Comment: It might work less well the other way around. The N7 has an almost completely stripped sleeve, making for a very long plug. Conversely my Galaxy Nexus has a quite short USB sleeve - I can't get it far enough into the N7 for it to charge. (The micro-usb standard clearly isn't quite prescriptive enough!)

Comment: @theTuxRacer ...a really bad omen... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Charging my Samsung Galaxy Note 1 (GT-N7000) since 2 Months with my Nexus 7 charger without problems.
The Nexus 7 charger provides enough output and the phone manages this.

But vice versa: Most phone chargers have less output (1A) so it needs longer to charge your Nexus 7 tablet.